# Downcasting to protocol with default values in protocol extension

Tags: swift, protocols, downcast

After downcasting an array of structs, my Variables View window shows that all of the values in my struct have shifted "down" (will explain in a second). But when I print(structName), the values are fine. However, when I run an equality check on the struct, it once again behaves as though my values have shifted.

For example, I am trying to downcast Model A to ModelProtocol. var m = Model A and has the values {id: "1234", name: "Cal"}. When I downcast, m now has the values { id:"\0\0", name:"1234" }.

After downcasting an array of structs, my Variables View window shows that all of the values in my struct have shifted "down" (will explain in a second). But when I print(structName), the values are fine. However, when I run an equality check on the struct, it once again behaves as though my values have shifted.

For example, I am trying to downcast Model A to ModelProtocol. var m = Model A and has the values {id: "1234", name: "Cal"}. When I downcast, m now has the values { id:"\0\0", name:"1234" }.

Actual Example Below:

Models that I want to downcast:

```
struct PrivateSchoolModel: Decodable, SchoolProtocol {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var city: String
    var state: String
}

struct PublicSchoolModel: Decodable, SchoolProtocol {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var city: String
    var state: String  
    var latitude: String
    var longitude: String
}
```

Protocol I want to downcast to:

```
protocol SchoolProtocol {
    var id: String { get set }
    var name: String { get set }
    var city: String { get set }
    var state: String { get set }
    var longitude: Float { get set }
    var latitude: Float { get set }
}

extension SchoolProtocol {
    var longitude: Float {
        get { return -1.0 }
        set {}
    }
    var latitude: Float {
        get { return -1.0 }
        set {}
    }
}
```

Downcasting:

```
guard let downcastedArr = privateSchoolArray as? [SchoolProtocol] else { return [] }
```

Result (item at index 0) or originalArr:

```
id = "1234"
name = "Leo High School"
city = "Bellview"
state = "WA"
```

Result (item at index 0) of downcastedArr:

```
id = "\0\0"
name = "1234"
city = "Leo High School"
state = "Bellview"
```

But if I print(downcastArr[0]), it will show:

```
id = "1234"
name = "Leo High School"
city = "Bellview"
state = "WA"
```

But if I try originalArray[0].id == downcastArr[0].id, it returns false

My Code with the problem:

```
class SchoolJSONHandler {
    private enum JSONFile: String {
        case publicSchool = "publicSchool"
        case privateSchool = "privateSchool"
    }

    private lazy var privateSchoolArray = getPrivateSchools()
    private lazy var publicSchoolArray = getPublicSchools()

    func getSchoolArray(sorted: Bool, filtered: Bool, by stateAbbreviation: String?) -> [SchoolProtocol] {
        var schools = combineArrays()

        if sorted {
            schools.sort(by: { $0.name < $1.name })
        }

        if filtered {
            guard let abbr = stateAbbreviation else { return [] }
            schools = schools.filter {
                return $0.state == abbr
            }
        }

        return schools
    }

    private func combineArrays() -> [SchoolProtocol] {
        // EVERYTHING IS FINE IN NEXT LINE
        let a = privateSchoolArray
        // PROBLEM OCCURS IN NEXT 2 LINES WHEN DOWNCASTING
        let b = privateSchoolArray as [SchoolProtocol]
        let c = publicSchoolArray as [SchoolProtocol]
        return b + c
    }

    private func getPublicSchools() -> [PublicSchoolModel] {
        guard let jsonData = getJSONData(from: .publicSchool) else { return [] }
        guard let schools = decode(jsonData: jsonData, using: [PublicSchoolModel].self) else { return [] }
        return schools
    }

    private func getPrivateSchools() -> [PrivateSchoolModel] {
        guard let jsonData = getJSONData(from: .privateSchool) else { return [] }
        guard let schools = decode(jsonData: jsonData, using: [PrivateSchoolModel].self) else { return [] }
        return schools
    }

    private func getJSONData(from resource: JSONFile) -> Data? {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: resource.rawValue, withExtension: "json")!
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)

            return jsonData
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }

        return nil
    }

    private func decode<M: Decodable>(jsonData: Data, using modelType: M.Type) -> M? {
        do {
            //here dataResponse received from a network request
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let model = try decoder.decode(modelType, from:
                jsonData) //Decode JSON Response Data

            return model
        } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

And then it is just called in another class by `schoolJSONHandler.getSchoolArray(sorted: true, filtered: true, by: "WA")`

Comment: Can you show the SchoolProtocol definition? You are casting [PrivateSchoolModel] and [PublicSchoolModel] to [SchoolProtocol] but you don't show what SchoolProtocol is. Maybe that would help in answering your question.

Comment: @iamluisg Sorry, it was just named wrong in the question. Fixed